# Input String is not a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

Have been trying this for days now, i want to view my recorded data for an update purpose by double clicking on the informations from data grid view, meanwhile i get "Input String was not in a correct format" error. My code:

```
private void dgvGroundtech_Double Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

if(dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
{
Id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[0].ToString());
txtName.Text = dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[1].ToStrings();
   txtItem.Text = dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[2].ToStrings();
   txtMobileNumber.Text = dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[3].ToStrings();
   cmbPurpose.Text = dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[4].ToStrings();
   txtAddress.Text = dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[5].ToStrings();
   txtAmount.Text = dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[6].ToStrings();
   txtDate.Text = dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[7].ToStrings();
}
}
```

Comment: Presumably `dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[0].ToString()` is not something that can be converted to an integer, what is its value?  What is the complete stack trace?

Comment: What is the value of dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[0] and what does the  ToStrings() method do?

Comment: The value is 0, int Id = 0;

Comment: @Pils  jhen is not asking about the resulting (or original) value of `Id`, but of the row value that should be converted to an int, but fails. *That* value is probably empty or not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

This line will potentially throw a format exception.

```
Id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[0].ToString());
```

Check the values for this

```
dgvGroundtech.CurrentRow.Cells[0].ToString()
```

do not fall into this category::

"value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9)."